# Conditional class style binding in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I want to make that styles are added to images only under a certain condition.

Here is code:

```
<div>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in productsList" :key="item.id" class="cart-img">
    <img
        v-if="item.file"
        :src="
           `https://server.com/${
            index === productsListBigIndex ? item.fileWide : item.file
              }`
            "
        :alt="item.altText || item.text"
        draggable="false"
    />
    <img
        v-else
        :alt="item.altText || item.text"
        :src="'https://server.com/empty.png'"
    />
    <p style="font-size: medium">{{item.text}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The style should depend on the `index` and `productsListBigIndex`. For example, if the index is 0 or 2, then this style (in particular the size of the picture) will be added, otherwise it will not.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div v-bind:class="[isActive ? activeClass : '', errorClass]"></div>
```

Like this you can conditionally add or remove a classname and styles specified,

Answer (score 0):

```
v-bind:class="getClass()"

methods:{
 getClass(){

   //logic to check the condition and return the class name
 }
}
```